# Global change in one word LaTeX

Tags: fonts, colors, latex

Does anyone know how to change font (color, size and bold/italic) of a *one word* globally in whole text?

For example:

> I have a **cat**. My **cat** is nice. My **cat**'s name is Morron.

I need some kind of function that will apply my preferences to whole document (like cat in my example).

Comment: The HTML code you’ve posted is misleading since it only changes a single occurrence, not all of them.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [xesearch](https://ctan.org/pkg/xesearch?lang=de) package and compile with XeLaTeX. There, you can search for specific words and apply macros on them, e.g. `\emph` or `\textbf` or `\textcolor{}`

So, for example you want to have every occurance of `cat` being italic, do

```
% Compile this with XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xesearch}    

% Define make-bold macro
\SearchList{mbold}{\textit{#1}}{cat}

\begin{document}

    cat, dog, duck, cat, donkey, monkey.

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

As you can see it is even case-sensitive. To suppress this, use `\SearchList*{}`